# Is it possible to create a Flash video player that plays videos hosted on youtube

Tags: javascript, html, flash, youtube

I want to create a custom video player to modify the skin of the play controls etc but still host the videos on youtube.

The youtube api allows for minor colour adjustments but not full customisation.

I know it would be possible if I download the FLVs but i want the video to remain hosted on youtube.

Is this possible?

Or is there a way of using the 'chromeless player' and creating custom controls around it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using chromeless player with the [official AS3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html)?

In [player parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html?playerVersion=AS3) you can just set `controls` to 0:

> controls
>
> Values: 0 or 1. Default is 1. This
>   parameter indicates whether the video
>   player controls will display. If this
>   parameter is set to 0, then the player
>   controls will not display, causing the
>   player to look like the chromeless
>   player.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible ... you can check [this](http://code.google.com/p/php-youtube-downloader/) to see how to get the url to the video

Comment: From the link: "This script is NO LONGER WORKING and is discontinued."

Comment: My answer is more than 7 years old. Probably you should look for more up-to-date answer or ask your own

Answer (score 0):

I've concluded that the only way to create custom controls for the youtube player that plays videos hosted on youtube (rather than playing FLVs) is to use the chromeless player without controls and then juse html/css/jquery to create the controls, for example:

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html?playerType=chromeless&playerVersion=as3